# Backbone.js - preload external template with Require.js text plugin

Tags: templates, backbone.js, requirejs

I want to load external HTML template for Backbone view with Require.js text! plugin and make template path custom (get template path from View 'template' property). The problem is - template loads asynchronously and on render I still not have it. Here is my code:

custom View

```
define([
    'views/abstract/base-view',
], function (BaseView) {

    var AppView = BaseView.extend({

        el: '#app-view',

        template: 'app-view',

        initialize: function () {

            this.on('template:loaded', this.render, this);

            BaseView.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);

        },

        render: function () {

            this.$el.empty();

            var html = this.template();

            this.$el.html(html);
        }
    });

    return AppView;

});
```

and abstract View to inherit

```
define([], function () {

    var AbstractView = Backbone.View.extend({

        initialize: function(){
            this.setTemplate();
        },

        setTemplate: function(){
            var that = this;
            require(['3p/text!templates/' + this.template + '.tpl'], function(tpl) {
                that.template = _.template(tpl);
                that.trigger('template:loaded');
            });
        }
    });

    return AbstractView;

});
```

It works but I don't like to listen to 'template:loaded' event for render. Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. 
To avoid the async behaviour, there is no another way than add in some file the requires that will be dynamic and load all of them before.

I made something similar to an inject. I loaded in a require all the dynamic templates and put in a shared dictionary the paths of the template. Then I use _.template(require(inject["templateNAME"])) and I get the template at the moment.

The idea is something like the next:

```
define(["require"], function (require) {
    require(["text!path/of/the/template",
             ...  ]);

    window.inject = {};
    inject.templateNAME = "text!path/of/the/template";
```

Then you will use something like this:

```
var tpl = require(inject[this.templateName]);
this.template = _.template(tpl);
```